# Java Compression Library To Support Deflate64

Tags: java, zip, compression, deflate, apache-commons-compress

Looking for an alternative compression java library to Apache Commons Compress (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/). Commons Compress throws an error when trying to read a zip entry that was compressed using "ENHANCED_DEFLATED" which is deflate64. Here is sample excerpt that throws the exception.

```
public void doRecurseZip(File inputFile)
        throws IOException{
    ZipFile srcZip = null;
    srcZip = new ZipFile(inputFile);

    final Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> entries = srcZip.getEntries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final ZipArchiveEntry srcEntry = entries.nextElement();
        String entryFilename = srcEntry.getName();
        String entryMimetype = "application/octet-stream";
        boolean canRead = srcZip.canReadEntryData(srcEntry);
        InputStream zipStream = srcZip.getInputStream(srcEntry);
        zipStream.close();
    }
    srcZip.close();
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the stack trace:

> org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.UnsupportedZipFeatureException: unsupported feature method 'ENHANCED_DEFLATED' used in entry test.docx
>       at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipUtil.checkRequestedFeatures(ZipUtil.java:357)
>       at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:404)
>       at ZippingAround.doRecurseZip(ZippingAround.java:23)

Does anyone know of another zip library that could replace Commons Compress, or possibly work in conjunction with it for the deflate64 compression method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In February 2018, Apache released [Compress v1.16](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) which includes support for `ENHANCED_DEFLATED`, ie. `Deflate64`. I needed this support and found that it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

[zlib](http://zlib.net/) has a Deflate64 decompressor (in C) in the contrib/infback9 directory. You would need to integrate that into your zip decoder.

Answer (score 0):

The [7zip-javabinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/index.html) library uses JNI to wrap 7zip which supports Deflate64. It provides platform specific solutions, or if you are so inclined they also provide an `all-platforms` solution.

The libraries are available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csevenzipjbinding).

If someone finds a pure Java solution please post another answer! :-)