# ZipInputStream not compatible with my zip file - invalid CEN header (bad compression method)

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to read a zip file, in java, using java "1.8.0_92" (the latest supported version for my OS.

Unfortunately, I am getting an exception:

> `invalid CEN header (bad compression method)`

When I use the *nix (actually OS X) `file` command to analyse the file I get the detail:

> `Zip archive data, at least v2.1 to extract`

Is there a third-party unzip library I can use that is capable of reading this version of zip file?

Answer (score 1):

According [Zip page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Compression_methods), version 2.1 of ZIP format specification added support to `Deflate64` compression:

> 2.1: (1996) Deflate64 compression

<strike>There is unresolved [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COMPRESS-380) for Apache Commons Compress.
At this time, as I know, the only library supporting this is [net.sf.sevenzipjbinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/index.html), but it is only wrapper to 7-Zip.</strike>
Feature request for Apache Commons Compress is resolved now, you can use it.

Related question: [Java Compression Library To Support Deflate64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299045/java-compression-library-to-support-deflate64)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons compressor can handle decompression of Deflate64 file type.

Need to add dependency in POM.xml.

- GroupId: org.apache.commons
- artifactId: commons-compress
- version: 1.21

Using class **ZipArchiveInputStream** with zip file Path passed as parameter.

```
ZipArchiveInputSteam ZipArchiveInputSteam = new ZipArchiveInputSteam(new FileInputStream(yourZipPath));
ZipArchiveEntry entry; 
while((entry = zipInput.getNextZipEntry()) != null){
    //Add Condition here to check Directory and then User FileOutputStream methods write(buffer,0,bytesRead) to write data to destination Path.
```